# In the extended real number system, what is it called the property of $mX < n\infty$ with all positive $m$, $n$, $X$?

Tags: terminology, real-numbers

I can understand the *extended* real number system on a conceptual level (as a non-mathematician nor a student majoring in it), where *any real number cannot be bigger than (a multiple of) infinity*.

What I'm wondering now is that how I can call this kind of property, like some entities (infinity here) are *always* larger than other entities (real numbers). Does it have a name in the first place?

The reason why I'm searching for it is that I'm constructing a kind of *prioritized* distance metric, where some distances should be considered first before any other distances in the scene.

Answer (score 0):

This property is a certain type of *completion* of the real line, although you're most likely to hear it being called a *two-point compactification.*